# How to loop through an array and calculate the sum using angular rxjs

Tags: angular, rxjs

const activityDetails = [

```
{
    username: "Tester",

    pointDetails: [

        {
            points: 4826,
            pointType: "BONUS"
        },
        {
            points: 9652,
            pointType: "BASE"
        },
        {
            points: 14478,
            pointType: "CLS"
        }
    ]
},
{
    username: "Tester2",
    pointDetails: [
        {
            points: 1126,
            pointType: "BONUS"
        },
        {
            points: 9652,
            pointType: "BASE"
        },
        {
            points: 44566,
            pointType: "CLS"
        }
    ]
}
```

]

Below is the code which i am trying to iterate over the array and count the point of BONUS and BASE. Am i missing something or is there any better way to iterate through the array and count the number? thanks

```
activityDetails.filter(n=>{
       n.pointDetails.reduce((sum:any, rates:any) => {
     if (rates.pointType === "BONUS" || rates.pointType === "BASE") {
       sum+= rates.points;
       console.log(sum);
     }

   }, 0)

   })
```

Comment: Can you show what you've already tried. There is plenty of documentation on `reduce`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to solve this with reduce you could do it like:

```
this.details.reduce((sum, current: { sum: number, sumType: string }) => {
      if (current.sumType === 'BONUS' || current.sumType === 'BASE') {
        sum += current.sum;
      }
      return sum;
    }, 0)
```

This accumulates the `sum` property of your objects, but only if the `sumType` is `'BASE'` or `'BONUS'`